# What term is used for the type of music that evokes a strong picture?

Tags: single-word-requests, music

Some songs, such as *Rodeo* by Aaron Copland and *Symphony No. 1* by Daniel Bukvich can evoke strong images in listener's ears. *Rodeo* has listeners imagining a wild west setting while *Symphony No. 1* evokes a terrifying battle. This may require listeners to have a specific cultural background or some knowledge of the song's history before listening, but once listener's know this background, they can imagine what is happening. Although other music may evoke imagery, the composers of these two songs were very intentional and specific in what imagery they want listeners to imagine. When played at a concert, the audience is often told beforehand about the story.

Is there any term, perhaps a music genre, or word that musicologists or scholars of music use, or word from other similar creative fields that can be applied to music, to refer specifically to such music that is intentionally composed in a way that creates intended imagery for listeners?

Sample sentence: *Rodeo* and *Symphony No. 1* are both examples of ___ music.

Comment: ***programme music*** noun [mass noun]
music that is intended to evoke images or convey the impression of events. Compare with absolute music. - OED

Comment: ... and of course *Peter and the Wulf* is another example

Comment: Years ago, I played a track of Debussy's 'The Girl with the Flaxen hair' for an inner city class of 11yr olds to draw something, anything. They weren't told the title. Nearly all drew a blonde girl. Impressionist at its best!

Comment: There are two good answers here, depending on the asker's desired meaning. If you're looking for a word that means a type of music INTENDED to convey strong imagery, programmatic music (as opposed to absolute music) is the better term. On the other hand, if you want a word that means music which conveys strong imagery effectively, then evocative is the right choice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Music that is *intended* to evoke a picture in the listener's mind is termed *program(me) music*. *Rodeo* is certainly this. I'm not familiar with the symphony you mention, so I don't know whether the composer intended it to suggest a battle. The typical symphony is *absolute music* (written for its own sake), but some symphonies have a programme, e.g. R. Strauss's Alpine Symphony.

Comment: The OED seems to favor "mme" - who knew?!

Comment: @Fattie Why wouldn't it? Oxford is in England.

Comment: From [Daniel Bukvich's website:](http://www.bukvichmusic.com/comp/symphonyno1/index.php) "There is a program underlying Symphony No. 1. It is meant to depict the fierce Allied bombing attacks on Dresden, Germany, on February 13–14, 1945, which, according to most recent estimates, killed between 25,000 and 30,000 people. The four movements, “Prologue”, “Seeds in the Wind”, “Ave Maria”, and “Firestorm”, are derived from *The Destruction of Dresden*, an historic account of the bombings written by David Irving."

Comment: Isn't programme music more about evoking a _sequence_ of images — and perhaps even a narrative linking them?

Answer (score 18):

Funnily enough… ***evocative***.

[OED](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/evocative):

> adj. Bringing strong images, memories, or feelings to mind.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/evocative):

> making you remember or imagine something pleasant: evocative music
>   a sound evocative of the sea

[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/evocative):

> making people remember something by producing a feeling or memory in them
>
> > evocative of
> >     a picture that is wonderfully evocative of a hot, summer’s day
> >     evocative music

Comment: This is just a general adjective.  The question couldn't be clearer:  ***Is there any term, perhaps a music genre, or word that musicologists or scholars of music use***

Comment: @Fattie The answer couldn't be clearer, and this is it. This is literally the word that was asked for. It's even got the same stem. This is the word that musical scholars use. And I'm a musician. So, y'know...

Comment: @Fattie: By semantical definition, something that evokes [something] is evocative. The listed definition in the answer fits OP's question to a tee; and OP did not specify that the word _must_ come from the music industry ("perhaps" does not entail a requirement).

Comment: "Evocative" is a descriptive term. Whether a certain piece of music is evocative is a matter of opinion. But the OP asked for a term for a *type* of music. That is, an objective label for a category or genre of music.

Answer (score 1):

Music that is intentionally composed in a way that creates intended imagery for listeners could be called *picturesque*.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/picturesque)

> Definition of picturesque
>
> 1. a: resembling a picture : suggesting a painted scene
>
>    b: charming or quaint in appearance
> 2. : evoking mental images : VIVID

Answer (score 0):

As in:

> *Rodeo* has listeners **visualizing** a wild west setting.

[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/224009?redirectedFrom=visualize#eid)

> 1. transitive. To form a mental vision, image, or picture of (something not visible or present to the sight, or of an abstraction);
>      to make visible to the mind or imagination.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it [**expressive**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expressive):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>    **2** : serving to express, utter, or represent
>   // foul and novel terms *expressive* of rage
>   — H. G. Wells
>   **3** : effectively conveying meaning or feeling
>   // an *expressive* silence
>   // *expressive* line drawings

Of course, *expressive* can be used to describe more than just music. Pictures and visual memories are often associated with feelings. And pictures are representations of actual things.

Answer (score -3):

**Ballet**

*Rodeo* is a ballet.

> The ballet makes use of riding movements that Agnes de Mille devised with the assistance of Peggy van Praagh, for a recital in London by Peggy van Praagh and Hugh Laing in 1938. De Mille also made use of such vernacular forms as a square dance and a cadenza for a tap dancer.

From [Rodeo (ballet)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodeo_(ballet))

"Rodeo and Symphony No. 1 are both examples of ballet / balletic music."

(Edit: adding some information about ballet as a musical genre.)

I have just listened to Bukvich, and the term *ballet* may be strained in the context of the bombing of Dresden. However, Stravinsky's [Le sacre du printemps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rite_of_Spring) is quite strident and is also by definition a ballet.

One commenter has had some trouble because the term *ballet* evokes visual imagery of sugarplums, tutus, *grand jetés* (i.e., ballerinas, costumes, physical movements). While the term *ballet* does encompass choreographed movements, it is also a musical genre in its own right.

> Ballet as a music form progressed from simply a complement to dance, to a concrete compositional form that often had as much value as the dance that went along with it.

From [Ballet (music)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballet_(music)).

One would fall into an epistemological trap if one called *Rodeo* a *ballet* when one saw dancers dancing, but *symphonic* if one saw only cellists bowing. The musical genre is *ballet*, whether or not you see a *pas de deux*.

(end edit)

**Tone poem**

Not a single word, but a *tone poem* (like Holst's *The Planets*) is a contrasting genre from *absolute music* (like Bach's *Prelude No. 1 in C*).

> The *tone poem*, or symphonic poem, is a work that wholeheartedly acknowledges that need. It has a title that suggests a storyline, or at least a mood-sequence, with perhaps a helpful literary or pictorial parallel: Tchaikovsky’s *Romeo and Juliet*, Liszt’s *Tasso: Lament and Triumph* and Rachmaninov’s own *Isle of the Dead* are classic examples.

from [What is a... Tone Poem](http://www.classical-music.com/article/what-tone-poem)?

Rodeo and Symphony No. 1 are both examples of tone poems.

Comment: I think that Prof Bukvich may have strained the definition of *symphony*. Although there are four movements in the Bukvich Symphony No. 1, they are very short,  they are played without pause, they are for woodwinds and voices, and they do not follow the a symphonic sequence of allegro/adagio/scherzo/rondo. As for *musical genre*, this piece is much closer to the tone poem than to the symphony. There are also many parallels with *The Planets* (a paragon for *tone poem*). There is a soothing, romantic feel to "Ave Maria" and "Venus"; strident voices rising in "Fire storm" and "Neptune".

Comment: Ballet is a dance form involving music plus choreography, not a standalone musical form. De Mille was the choreographer for Rodeo, thus the "riding movements" referenced in your quote are not [musical movements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movement_(music)) but physical movements performed by human bodies.  Symphony No. 1 is absolutely _not_ a ballet as it was written with no accompanying choreography. The question strongly implies (by referring to 'listeners' repeatedly) that the music is being experienced as audio only, without any accompanying visual phenomena such as a dance troupe.

Comment: @Timbo, I respectfully disagree. Tchaikovsky (Nutcracker) and Copeland (Rodeo) wrote ballet music, which is a musical genre in its on right. The musical genre is called ballet. If you insist on the "visual phenomena," then what do you call Rodeo when you're streaming it? I also disagree in your assumption that the ballet genre must have accompanying choreography. The Nutcracker was ballet music before a choreographer put pen to paper and before the first ballerina donned a slipper.

Comment: It is fair to say that music written specifically for ballet is called ballet music, though things start to get fuzzy in the 20th century as forms split into classical, modern, and jazz. "Ballet music" definitely evokes classical forms. The Nutcracker was choreographed before it was scored: "Petipa gave Tchaikovsky extremely detailed instructions for the composition of each number, down to the tempo and number of bars."  If I were streaming the score to The Nutcracker I would call it a romantic classical symphony.  What to call the score to Rodeo is the whole point of this question.

Answer (score -3):

If the classical touch is not of importance, I would say [Ambient music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_music)

*Ambient music is a genre of music that emphasizes tone and **atmosphere** over traditional musical structure or rhythm. The genre is said to **evoke an "atmospheric", "visual"**, or "unobtrusive" quality.*